# Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to make a js game though when I try and trigger a function using `onclick` nothing happens and then when I went onto console it came up with this error message everytime I clicked it:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is how I define my function:

```
var myfunction = function () {
```

I know that it is nothing to do with the function though as I call it after I make it and it works fine.

I have also checked whether it is the click by putting an alert in the onclick though that worked fine.

I know this is a common problem, though have looked at others and found nothing.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/DQnmF/

JavaScript:

```
var attack = function () {
    while (slaying === true) {
        if (youHit !== 1) {
            totalDamage = totalDamage += damageThisRound;
            document.getElementById('hit').style.display = 'inline';  
            //alert('You hit!!! ' + totalDamage * 10 + ' damage');
            health = health - totalDamage * 10;
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('health').style.width = health + 'px'}, 400);
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hit').style.display = 'none'}, 500);
            if (totalDamage >= 4) {
                //alert('the dragons dead');
                slaying = false;
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById('miss').style.display = 'inline'; 
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('miss').style.display = 'none'}, 500);
            //alert('You missed');
        }
        slaying = false;
    }
}

document.getElementById('character').style.color = '#ccc';
document.getElementById('enemy').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('enemy').style.right = '0';
document.getElementById('game').style.position = 'relative';
document.getElementById('game').style.width = '1004px';
document.getElementById('characters').style.position = 'relative';
document.getElementById('health-container').style.right = '0';
document.getElementById('health-container').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('health-container').style.bottom = '30px';
document.getElementById('health-container').style.width = '200px';
document.getElementById('health-container').style.height = '41px';
document.getElementById('health').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
document.getElementById('health').style.height = '41px';
document.getElementById('health').style.width = '200px';
document.getElementById('miss').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('miss').style.right = '20px';
document.getElementById('miss').style.bottom = '120px';
document.getElementById('miss').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('hit').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('hit').style.right = '20px';
document.getElementById('hit').style.bottom = '120px';
document.getElementById('hit').style.display = 'none';
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
var num = document.getElementById('health').style.width.length - 2;
var health = document.getElementById('health').style.width;
health = health.substring(0, num);
attack();
```

Comment: Your declaration of "myfunction" is probably inside some function, and you're trying to use it from outside that function.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a jsFiddle?

Comment: I don't see enough information here to know for sure, but I think you should start looking at where you bind the function to the onclick event itself. There's just not nearly enough information here.

Comment: I'll try though i'm not sure

Comment: You should try to explain, or show code where we can see the scope of that function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/wAT7H/ this is a fiddle with a similar error

Comment: Do you want to post the actual code you're having trouble with? The fiddle and your question are different. You've posted a fiddle but your questoin say "I would prefer not to post a fiddle or too much more code if at all possible" - which is it?  Why not post more code, if it clarifies the problem? Are you sure that the error message is exactly this: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" and not something else?

Comment: Will post actual code

Comment: Your fiddle is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wAT7H/1/. You had an extra parenthesis and loaded it in the wrong spot.

Comment: you added way too much code and btw your code is quite buggy ( one example out of many "totalDamage = totalDamage += damageThisRound;" should be "totalDamage += damageThisRound;") you should also make css classes and use "document.getElementById(...).className = '...' " to help manage your code

Comment: @j08691 that wasn't my actual fiddle that was jsut an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the end. I used this instead of using the onclick method:

```
document.getElementById('attack').addEventListener('click', function() {
    myfunction();
}, false);
```